# Reply to Hono command on AMQP device

Tags: python, eclipse-hono, eclipse-iot

I'm trying to create a prototype device that is able to receive commands from hono and reply to it.

I've installed hono 1.10.0 and run the following python code

```
import threading
import time
from proton import Message
from proton.reactor import Container
from amqp import AmqpSender, AmqpReceiver
from hono import tenantId, deviceId, devicePassword, device_uri, biz_app_uri


correlation_id = 'myCorrelationId'
command_reply_to = f'command_response/{tenantId}/{correlation_id}'

print("Business application subscribing for the command reply--------------------------------------------")
cr_container = Container(AmqpReceiver(biz_app_uri, command_reply_to, "consumer@HONO", "verysecret"))
cr_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: cr_container.run(), daemon=True)
cr_thread.start()
# Give it some time to link
time.sleep(5)


print("Device subscribing for commands-------------------------------------------------------------------")
c_container = Container(AmqpReceiver(device_uri, f'command', f'{deviceId}@{tenantId}', devicePassword))
c_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: c_container.run(), daemon=True)
c_thread.start()
# Give it some time to link
time.sleep(2)


print("Business application sending a command------------------------------------------------------------")
msg = Message(
    address=f'command/{tenantId}/{deviceId}',
    reply_to=command_reply_to,
    correlation_id=correlation_id,
    content_type="text/plain",
    subject="call",
    body="Hello Bob!"
)
#as in example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698271/difficulty-in-sending-amqp-1-0-message
Container(AmqpSender(biz_app_uri, [msg], "consumer@HONO", "verysecret", address=f'command/{tenantId}')).run()
time.sleep(2)


print("Device sending a command response-----------------------------------------------------------------")
resp = Message(
    address=command_reply_to,
    correlation_id=correlation_id,
    content_type="text/plain",
    properties={
        'status': 200,
        'device_id': deviceId,
        'tenant_id': tenantId
    },
    subject="call",
    body="Hello Alice!"
)
Container(AmqpSender(device_uri, [resp], f'{deviceId}@{tenantId}', devicePassword)).run()
time.sleep(2)


print("Device stops listeing for commands----------------------------------------------------------------")
c_container.stop()
c_thread.join(timeout=5)
print("Business application stops listening for command responsets---------------------------------------")
cr_container.stop()
cr_thread.join(timeout=5)
print("everything stopped")
```

I did this implementation with the help of [Difficulty in Sending AMQP 1.0 Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698271/difficulty-in-sending-amqp-1-0-message) and according to my understanding of https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/command-and-control/ and https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/amqp-adapter/#sending-a-response-to-a-command.

For the moment i doesn't seem so wrong as the device receives the command, and also sending the message does not show any errors. However on the receiving end nothing arrives. Just to clarify, the AmqpReceiver implementation works for the scenario where I listen for telemetry data. Hence, if the implementation is supposed to be the same (aside a different address), then this should not be the issue.

I highly believe that I do something wrong with the address/reply_to in the message but I can't confirm as the logs in the hono pods don't tell me anything :(

br
Armin

======update===============================

the code i currently run is the follwoing

```
from proton import Message
from proton.handlers import MessagingHandler
from proton.reactor import AtLeastOnce


class Amqp(MessagingHandler):
    def __init__(self, server, address, user, password, options=None):
        super(Amqp, self).__init__()
        self.server = server
        self.address = address
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.options = options
        self.connection = None

    def create_connection(self, event):
        self.connection = event.container.connect(
            self.server,
            sasl_enabled=True,
            allowed_mechs="PLAIN",
            allow_insecure_mechs=True,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password
        )
        print("Connection established")

    def on_connection_error(self, event):
        print("Connection Error")

    def on_link_error(self, event):
        print("Link Error")

    def on_transport_error(self, event):
        print("Transport Error")

    def on_link_opened(self, event):
        if event.link.is_sender:
            print("Opened sender link")
        if event.link.is_receiver:
            print("Opened receiver link for source address '{0}'".format(event.receiver.source.address))


class AmqpReceiver(Amqp):
    def __init__(self, server, address, user, password, options=None):
        super(AmqpReceiver, self).__init__(server, address, user, password, options)
        self.server = server
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def on_start(self, event):
        self.create_connection(event)
        event.container.create_receiver(context=self.connection, source=self.address, options=self.options)
        print("Receiver created")

    def on_message(self, event):
        print(f'Receiver [{self.address}] got message:')
        print(f'  {event.message.reply_to}')
        print(f'  {event.message.correlation_id}')
        print(f'  {event.message.properties}')
        print(f'  {event.message.subject}')
        print(f'  {event.message.body}')
        #just for test purposes - the device sends imediatelly the reply if a reply_to is given
        if event.message.reply_to is not None:
            reply_to = event.message.reply_to.split('/')
            tenant_id = reply_to[1]
            device_id = reply_to[2]
            resp = Message(
                address=event.message.reply_to,
                correlation_id=event.message.correlation_id,
                content_type="text/plain",
                properties={
                    'status': 200,
                    'tenant_id': tenant_id,
                    'device_id': device_id
                },
                body=f'Reply on {event.message.body}'
            )
            sender = event.container.create_sender(self.connection, None, options=AtLeastOnce())
            sender.send(resp)
            sender.close()
            print("Reply send")


class AmqpSender(Amqp):
    def __init__(self, server, messages, user, password, address=None, options=None):
        super(AmqpSender, self).__init__(server, address, user, password, options)
        self.messages = messages

    def on_start(self, event):
        self.create_connection(event)
        event.container.create_sender(context=self.connection, target=self.address)
        print("Sender created")

    def on_sendable(self, event):
        print("In Msg send")
        for msg in self.messages:
            event.sender.send(msg)
        event.sender.close()
        event.connection.close()
        print("Sender & connection closed")
```

and in the test script i use that as follows

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import threading
import time
from proton import Message
from proton.reactor import Container
from amqp import AmqpSender, AmqpReceiver


biz_app_uri = f'amqp://localhost:15672'
device_uri = f'amqp://localhost:5672'
tenantId = 'ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8'
deviceId = 'b932fb15-fdbd-4c12-9ed7-40aaa8763412'

biz_app_user = 'consumer@HONO'
biz_app_pw = 'verysecret'
device_user = f'{deviceId}@{tenantId}'
device_pw = 'my-secret-password'

correlation_id = 'myCorrelationId'
command_reply_to = f'command_response/{tenantId}/{correlation_id}'


print("Business application subscribing for command replies-------------------------------------------")
cr_container = Container(AmqpReceiver(biz_app_uri, command_reply_to, biz_app_user, biz_app_pw))
cr_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: cr_container.run(), daemon=True)
cr_thread.start()
time.sleep(2)

print("Device subscribing for commands-------------------------------------------------------------------")
c_container = Container(AmqpReceiver(device_uri, f'command', device_user, device_pw))
c_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: c_container.run(), daemon=True)
c_thread.start()
time.sleep(2)

print("Business application sending a command------------------------------------------------------------")
msg = Message(
    address=f'command/{tenantId}/{deviceId}',
    reply_to=command_reply_to,
    correlation_id=correlation_id,
    content_type="text/plain",
    subject="call",
    body="Hello Bob!"
)
#as in example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698271/difficulty-in-sending-amqp-1-0-message
Container(AmqpSender(biz_app_uri, [msg], biz_app_user, biz_app_pw, address=f'command/{tenantId}')).run()

time.sleep(10)
print("Device stops listeing for commands----------------------------------------------------------------")
c_container.stop()
c_thread.join(timeout=5)
#print("Business application stops listening ---------------------------------------")
#cr_container.stop()
#cr_thread.join(timeout=5)
#print("everything stopped")
```

if i run that code sample i get the following logs (see bellow) and the code is stuck as the command reply receiver remains open.

log on hono dispatch router:

```
2021-11-14 19:08:29.420176 +0000 SERVER (info) enabling remote authentication service hono-1635540280-service-auth:5671
2021-11-14 19:08:29.429734 +0000 SERVER (info) [C115] Accepted connection to 0.0.0.0:5672 from 10.42.0.70:36742
2021-11-14 19:08:29.447479 +0000 AUTHSERVICE (info) authenticated as consumer@HONO
2021-11-14 19:08:29.448213 +0000 ROUTER (info) [C115] Connection Opened: dir=in host=10.42.0.70:36742 vhost= encrypted=no auth=PLAIN user=consumer@HONO container_id=a782f51c-9679-41fb-a682-8ea603ccf1ac props=
2021-11-14 19:08:29.448316 +0000 ROUTER_CORE (info) [C115][L123] Link attached: dir=out source={command_response/ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8/myCorrelationId expire:sess} target={<none> expire:sess}
2021-11-14 19:08:33.423325 +0000 SERVER (info) enabling remote authentication service hono-1635540280-service-auth:5671
2021-11-14 19:08:33.430810 +0000 SERVER (info) [C116] Accepted connection to 0.0.0.0:5672 from 10.42.0.70:36868
2021-11-14 19:08:33.445574 +0000 AUTHSERVICE (info) authenticated as consumer@HONO
2021-11-14 19:08:33.446328 +0000 ROUTER (info) [C116] Connection Opened: dir=in host=10.42.0.70:36868 vhost= encrypted=no auth=PLAIN user=consumer@HONO container_id=92cb7173-2940-4330-a995-f26eccef0905 props=
2021-11-14 19:08:33.446388 +0000 ROUTER_CORE (info) [C116][L124] Link attached: dir=in source={<none> expire:sess} target={command/ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8 expire:sess}
2021-11-14 19:08:33.447762 +0000 ROUTER_CORE (info) [C116][L124] Link detached: del=1 presett=0 psdrop=0 acc=0 rej=0 rel=0 mod=0 delay1=0 delay10=0 blocked=no
```

log on amqp adapter

```
2021-11-14 19:08:31,511 INFO [org.ecl.hon.ada.mon.LoggingConnectionEventProducer] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Connected - ID: 100b1859-e8a0-4bff-ad91-a48dce4babb5, Protocol Adapter: hono-amqp, Device: device [device-id: b932fb15-fdbd-4c12-9ed7-40aaa8763412, tenant-id: ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8], Data: null
2021-11-14 19:19:29,875 INFO [org.ecl.hon.ada.mon.LoggingConnectionEventProducer] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Disconnected - ID: 100b1859-e8a0-4bff-ad91-a48dce4babb5, Protocol Adapter: hono-amqp, Device: device [device-id: b932fb15-fdbd-4c12-9ed7-40aaa8763412, tenant-id: ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8], Data: null
```

Comment: > I've installed hono 1.10.9 and run the following python code


Can you be a little more specific? Did you deploy to a k8s cluster using the Helm chart? I also assume that you mean 1.10.0, right?

Comment: "However on the receiving end nothing arrives."  I assume you mean the north bound application which does not receive the command response sent by the device?

Comment: you are right about the hono version 1.10.0... seems that the helm version number differs from the app as i see

Comment: @ArminGruber Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the command response sent by your device contains the wrong address. As pointed out in the [AMQP Adapter User Guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/amqp-adapter/#sending-a-response-to-a-command), the response's `address` property must be set to the value of the `reply-to` property of the command. That value is usually NOT the same as the `reply-to` value that your application sets in the command message because the protocol adapter needs to encode some additional information into the reply to address in order to be able to determine the correct device ID when forwarding the command response downstream.

In your code you therefore need to inspect the command message at the device side and use its `reply-to` value as the command response's `address` value.

In addition to that, the AMQP adapter expects the status property in the command response to be of AMQP 1.0 type `int` (a 32 bit signed integer). However, with your code the property value is encoded as an AMQP 1.0 `long` (64 bit signed integer) by default. In order to encode it correctly, you need to import the `int32` class from `proton._data` and then set the property value as `int32(200)`. Then the adapter accepts the command response and forwards it downstream.

Comment: ok i see, you are right about the reply_to modification. 

the northbound app sends command_response/ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8/myCorrelationId

and the device receives command_response/ea8b6601-6fb7-4fb5-a097-2d9a3cdea0d8/b932fb15-fdbd-4c12-9ed7-40aaa8763412/0myCorrelationId.

however even if i set the address value with the later address value it doesn't end up at the receiver end. i'll update the new code (+the amqp part) in the question

Comment: In the meanwhile i changed the code a bit so that i have a callback function hand over to the AMQP receiver which is called in the on_message method. This callback takes the message get the variable reply_to value and set the address value with it. Unfortunately this didn't change the outcome :(

Comment: it is hard to follow what code you are actually running. Can you put your code into a gist or GitHub project?

Comment: Sure, i cleand it a bit up and simplified it so that it is a bit easier to read (hopefully)

https://github.com/armin85/hono-test

Comment: Hello Kai, i updated the code a bit in the repository mentioned in the comment above. Can you give me a hint what might be wrong as from the hono log perspektiv things look fine as far as i see them. i updated the question accordingly

Comment: In test_client_command.py the deviceId variable value is used for both the device authenticating to the AMQP adapter (`{deviceId}@{tenantId}`) as well as for sending the command to the device: address=f'command/{tenantId}/{deviceId}'. This will only work if you have used the device ID as the auth ID when you have registered the device and its credentials. That said, I have successfully run  your code using the Hono Sandbox with the DEFAULT_TENANT and device 4711 (using auth ID "sensor1").

Comment: Oh wait, I haven't yet seen the output of the business application on receiving the device's response ... will need to take another look

Comment: Ok, I figured out what the problem was. The AMQP adapter expects the status property in the command response to be of AMQP 1.0 type "int" (a 32 bit signed integer). However, with your code the property value is encoded as an AMQP 1.0 long (64 bit signed integer). In order to encode it correctly, you need to import the int32 class from proton._data and then set the property value as "int32(200)". Then the adapter accepts the command response and forwards it downstream.

Comment: i don't know how to thank you, things work now and i can start creating a first version a gateway collecting informations. Looking forward to have fun with hono :)

Comment: Let us know how you fare!